# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.parse.ParseObject.getClassName

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.parse.ParseObject.getClassName
at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.<init>(ParseQueryAdapter.java:179)
```

After migrating from parse platform to parse open server on heroku I updated the dependency to newer parse SDK to allow server url in parse initialization, 
app/build.gradle now has

```
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
```

---

i tried manually compiling the parse libraries from the jar 
compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0.jar')
but this results in error

```
Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

and even tried setting multiDexEnabled true but this results in another error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'. > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/parse/AbstractQueryController$1.class
```

---

### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    // Enabling multidex support.
    //multiDexEnabled true


}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.4'
compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.3@aar'
```

}

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya build.gradle added

Comment: call `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.12.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya that results in  error (because you need 1.13.0 the newer parse SDK to allow server url in parse initialization) : cannot find symbol
                        .server("http://myapp.herokuapp.com/parse/") // The trailing slash is important.
                        ^
  symbol:   method server(String)
  location: class Builder

Comment: `compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.1'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i tried 1.13.1 and get the same runtime error error;java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.parse.ParseObject.getClassName
at com.parse.ParseQueryAdapter.<init>(ParseQueryAdapter.java:179)

Answer (score 1):

got past this issue by changing

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, Todo.class);
```

to

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Todo");
```

---

error was pointing to 
ParseUI-Widget/src/main/java/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.java

```
public ParseQueryAdapter(Context context, Class<? extends ParseObject> clazz) {
this(context, ParseObject.getClassName(clazz));
```

}

at getClassName it said Non-Static method cannot be referenced from a static context